# php getaddrinfo failure: "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup."

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Would really appreciate your help please :) I keep getting an error on my PDO connect, as such: **Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.**

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class Database{
public $dbserver = '';
public $username = '';
public $password = '';
public $database = '';
public $db = '';
public function __construct(){
$this->dbserver = 'localhost';
$this->username = 'tiffinie';
$this->password = 'pword';
$this->database = 'practicedb';
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbserver.";dbname=".$this->database, $this->username, $this->password);
}
public function dbselect($table, $select, $where=NULL){
}
public function dbadd($tablename, $insert, $format){
}
public function dbupdate($tablename, $insert, $where){
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that the server that hosts your app doesn't know how to resolve "localhost".

See the [hosts](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap9sec95.html) file for this.

You can workaround that by replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Define a name for your SQL server in the http config file, or try with IP address like 127.0.0.1

And make sure database is running

Comment: Hi! Database is setup.  I tried replacing "localhost" to the IP address but now the page isn't available; won't even load :(