# Errors while connecting to database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, localhost

I get the errors when i try to connect to my mysql database, and I dont know how to fix them:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_errno() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_close() in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 16
```

Heres the source code.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "widget_cms";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "wigetcorp";
$datab = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_errno()){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . " )");
}
?>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close($datab);

?>
```

The password isnt blank though, I just made it blank to put it in here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591831/php-getaddrinfo-failure-a-non-recoverable-error-occurred-during-a-database-loo it is suggested to change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: `mysql_close($datab);` use mysqli...